# How can I access to Circuit sandbox?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'm unabled to connect to my circuit sandbox for two days already. I tried to request new sandbox but there are error message. Do I missed some changes of how sandbox work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, but the only circuit sandbox datacenter is in Southflorida and it has been shut down due to hurricane Dorian. Should be up tomorrow.

We are looking at better announcing this, and moreover use multiple data centers so such downtime will not happen anymore.

Comment: Is there any update on this? The swagger definition page for the API has been restored but the Web Client still cannot login. Additionally the API calls via swagger return 401 Unauthorized with credentials that used to be valid.

Comment: Rest API seems to be fully functional at the moment.